# Infinite subset of finite complement space intersects open sets

Tags: general-topology

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Infinite_Subset_of_Finite_Complement_Space_Intersects_Open_Sets

In this wikipedia page I didn't understand that ....why  H intersection closure of U is finite ..
Because closure of U is bigger than U so intersection of H with closure of U must be bigger than U..

Comment: This is *not* a Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 0):

$\complement_S \left({U}\right)$ stands for complement. Not closure.

Answer (score 0):

If $H$ is infinite in $X$ (an infinite set with the finite-complement topology) and $U$ is non-empty open, this means that $X\setminus U$ is finite.
So $H$, being infinite, is *not* a subset of $X \setminus U$, so there is an $x \in H$, such that $x \notin X\setminus U$, or equivalently $x \in U$. So $U \cap H \neq \emptyset$.

The proof on the referred page uses $C_S(U)$ for $S \setminus U$. (i.e. complement of $U$ inside $S$, which is the whole space, where I used $X$).

Comment: Thankew for the help